# Does including the background-image property within the :hover pseudo-class cause an image to be served again?

Tags: html, css

I've got a page with an HTML element that contains a background image, with opacity specified in the `background-image` property; the purpose of specifying opacity in this manner is to avoid impacting the opacity of anything in that div other than the image.

```
#my_div {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient( rgba(255,255,255, 0.5), rgba(255,255,255, 0.5) ),
        url("../images/my_image.jpg");
}
```

The opacity of the image changes when the user hovers over it:

```
#my_div:hover {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient( rgba(255,255,255,   1), rgba(255,255,255,   1) ), 
        url("../images/my_image.jpg");
}
```

- Are there cases when doing the above cause the server to re-deliver the same image that has already been downloaded by the user (i.e. does it cause an inefficient use of bandwidth)?
- If so, what's a good way to avoid delivering the image file to the user multiple times, while maintaining the effect that's produced by the above CSS code?

Comment: None if it's cached already? Check the console and see if it says 'from cache', if it does, then nope it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there cases when doing the above cause the server to re-deliver the same image that has already been downloaded by the user (i.e. does it cause an inefficient use of bandwidth)?

No, the browser will have the image cached. In a web environment resources are only requested once and then cached, unless the file was annotated with an `Expires` header such that it expires before the next time it is needed - or the cache is full and the image deleted. Static files generally don't expire so only one request will be made for `my_image.jpg`, you can use your browser's <kbd>F12</kbd> tools window to inspect the requests and see that only one is made, no matter how many times you hover-over the element or even reload the page (unless you reload with <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> of course).

> If so, what's a good way to avoid delivering the image file to the user multiple times, while maintaining the effect that's produced by the above CSS code?

While I've answered your question to confirm that it will only be sent once, you might want to consider using `data:` URIs for trivial resources (e.g. 16x16 pixel-art, icons, etc) to avoid the latency involved in making a separate request for that resource - though unfortunately if you want to specify a `data:` URI resource multiple times you cannot alias them to avoid having to repeat the file's code.